# why is it possible to use 'string' as the name of a variable

Tags: c++, string

I'm a beginner in C++ and I'm doing one of the exercises in Stroustrup's `Programming Principles And Practice Using C++`.
This exercise wants me to experiment with legal and illegal names.

```
void illegal_names()
{
//    the compiler complains about these which made sense:
//    int double =0;
//    int if =0;
//    int void = 0;
//    int int = 0;
//    int while =0;
//    string int = "hello";
//    
//    however, this is legal and it runs without a problem:
    double string = 0.0;
    cout << string<< endl;

}
```

My question is, what makes `string` different than any other types? Are there other types that is special like `string`?

Comment: `string` isn't a keyword.

Comment: as chris said, `string` isn't special, and that's the special thing about it.

Comment: There are keywords and names in the namespace std (none of the names, introduced in the namespace std, is a keyword)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string` is not a keyword so it may be used as an identifier. All other statemenets in the code segment are erroneous because there are used keywords as identifiers.

As for standard class `std::string` then you can even write in a block scope

```
std::string string;
```

In this case the identifier `string` declared in the block scope will hides type `std::string`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string string = "Hello, string";
    std::cout << string << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

All of those other names are reserved words in the C++ language. But "string" is not. Even though `string` is a commonly used data type, it is built out of more basic types and defined in a library which itself is written in C++.

Comment: Furthermore, the `string` type is declared in namespace `std`, so even an `#include <string>` would not produce a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

in C++ `std::string` is a defined data type (class), not a keyword. it's not forbidden to use it as variable name. it is not a reserved word. consider a C++ program, which also works:

```
#include <iostream>

class xxx {
    int x;
public:
    xxx(int x_) : x(x_) {}
    int getx() { return x;}
};

int main()
{
    xxx c(4);
    std::cout << c.getx() << "\n";
    int xxx = 4;  // this works
    std::cout << xxx << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

this the same case as with `string`. xxx is user defined data type and as you can see it is not reserved. 

the image below shows list of reserved keywords in c++.
[image]